# How to access/change boxplot features in a Seaborn catplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn box plot (constructed as a catplot with kind=box) and it basically looks how I want it to except I want to change some of the features of the box plot (linewidth around the boxes and the gap in between the dodged/hue boxes).

There are parameters to do this if I use sns.boxplot (gap=x etc) but these aren't recognised if I enter them in the sns.catplot function.

I'm guessing I need to access some keywords for the underlying boxplot function but I can't work out how to do it.

NOTE = if I plot as sns.boxplot I run into other problems with the legend

I am creating a catplot (kind=box) to show relationships between a category (cat1), float (var1) and integer (var2), this is the code:

```
g = sns.catplot(data = dataframe,
                        x="var1",
                        y="var2",
                        hue="cat1",
                        kind="box",
                        height=3.5,
                        aspect=1,
                        showfliers=False,
                        whis=(2, 98),
                        width=0.5,
                        legend=False,
                        )

g_eff.fig.get_axes()[0].legend(loc='lower left')
```

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lazV.png)

Comment: Concerning *"if I plot as sns.boxplot I run into other problems with the legend"*: you can use `sns.move_legend()` to move the legend and change many of its parameters.

Comment: Could you try to add reproducible data (or maybe use one of seaborn's default datasets) to create a reproducible example? Could you also add how you would call `sns.boxplot()` with the additional parameters (or describe them in more detail)? Which seaborn version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

`catplot` with `kind="box"` accepts all of the additional formatting kwargs that `boxplot` does. e.g. with the specific customizations mentioned in your question:

```
sns.catplot(tips, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", linewidth=.5, gap=.1, kind="box")
```

[image]

The `gap` parameter was added in v0.13 so if you're finding that it's not working when you try maybe that is because you have an older version locally?

Note that `boxplot` (and hence `catplot` with `kind="box"`) exposes more additional customization through parameters with unconventional (for seaborn) names such as `boxprops`, `capprops`, etc. because these are parameters of the underlying [matplotlib function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html). You should be able to use them to achieve a very high level of customization (higher in v0.13 than in previous versions as the logic was reworked to honor the user's parameterization over seaborn's default customization in most places).

Comment: I didn't have the latest version of seaborn so couldn't use the gap kw. I'll update and I'm sure that will fix it, thanks!